# Instance Counting Properly with Sub Classes

Tags: python-3.x, oop, inheritance, instance, counting

I'm experimenting with OOP, and am trying to implement some class inheritance with counts of the number of instances of each class and subclass.

I'd like to have a class variable that is incremented inside the class' `__init__` method, such that when I create an instance of a class, the count for that class and for all its parents and grandparent classes is incremented.

However, after a number of attempts I'm struggling to achieve this while isolating the counts for each subclass from the parent class.

Say I have the classes 'Cls', 'SubCls', and 'SubSubCls' as below.

```
class Cls():
    count = 0

    def __init__(self):
        #general init stuff
        self.__class__.count += 1

class SubCls(Cls):
    pass

class SubSubCls(SubCls):
    pass
```

I'd like the following behaviour:

```
a = Cls()
SubSubCls.count #returns 0
SubCls.count    #returns 0
Cls.count       #returns 1

b = SubCls()
SubSubCls.count #returns 0
SubCls.count    #returns 1
Cls.count       #returns 2

c = SubSubCls()
SubSubCls.count #returns 1
SubCls.count    #returns 2
Cls.count       #returns 3
```

The rational for this being that if Cls is something like 'Entity', SubCls is 'Physical Entity', and SubSubCls is 'Tree' and I create one instance of Tree, I now have 1 Tree, 1 Physical Entity, 1 Entity - even though they're all in one object.

The best I've come up with so far is the following:

```
class Cls():
    count = 0

    def __init__(self):
        #general init stuff
        self.inc_count()

    def inc_count(self):
        Cls.count += 1
        super().inc_count() #removing this avoids AttributeError but means having
                            # unique methods for inc_count in all SubCls level Classes
class SubCls(Cls):
    count = 0

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        #unique init stuff

    def inc_count(self):
        SubCls.count += 1
        super().inc_count()        


class SubSubCls(SubCls):
    count = 0

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        #unique init stuff

    def inc_count(self):
        SubSubCls.count += 1
        super().inc_count()
```

This has the correct behaviour, but I feel the inheritance should be able to be better. I don't want to have to define `inc_count()` separately for each class when they're so similar - I want to keep things scalable here.

1. I can see cases with multiple inheritance to be a complication in the future, but I'll leave that alone for now.
2. I'm sure I can get around the `super().inc_count()` in the definition for `Cls` causing an AttributeError either using try and except or by defining a `MetaCls` above `Cls` - so I'm not too worried there.
3. However, I'm pretty sure I can't simply replace the  `Cls.count += 1`, `SubCls.count += 1`, and `SubSubCls.count += 1` in the `inc_count()` definition with a `self.__class__.count += 1` or `type(self).count += 1` as that would just lead to action on the count of the 'lowest' class of the instance multiple times over. (i.e. creating an instance of SubSubCls would lead to the count of SubSubCls increasing by 3 overall, and the counts of its parent classes being unchanged).

To solve this, is there an abstract way to reference the Class a method has been inherited from? So that my inc_count is only defined at the top level as something like this (and inherited by all the subclasses).

```
def inc_count(self):
    DirectParentClassDefinedAtRunTime.count += 1
    super().inc_count()
```

Obviously, if I'm going about getting the desired effect the wrong way entirely I'd be glad for any pointers. My only previous foray into OOP was with Flash at the age of 12 - a long time ago now.

Answer (score 0):

I would make use of the MRO (method resolution order) to do this (using `defaultdict` for simplicity but other structures work too):

```py
from collections import defaultdict


class Cls:
    counts = defaultdict(int)
    
    def __init__(self):
        for cls in self.__class__.__mro__:
            self.counts[cls] += 1
    
    @classmethod
    def get_count(cls) -> int:
        return cls.counts[cls]


class SubCls(Cls):
    pass


class SubSubCls(SubCls):
    pass
```

This has the behaviour you describe:

```py
a = Cls()
SubSubCls.get_count() # returns 0
SubCls.get_count()    # returns 0
Cls.get_count()       # returns 1

b = SubCls()
SubSubCls.get_count() # returns 0
SubCls.get_count()    # returns 1
Cls.get_count()       # returns 2

c = SubSubCls()
SubSubCls.get_count() # returns 1
SubCls.get_count()    # returns 2
Cls.get_count()       # returns 3
```